# How to properly test a Django library

Tags: python, django, plugins

I frequently run into practical problems when I want to test a library I develop which is a Django app. Django apps can be developed independently, like [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), etc.

For testing, you either need a Django project, or at least a settings.py file or the like, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage).

But I don't get how to do that properly for a "standalone" library. I need to generate migrations for that library (if it contains models) - so I need a manage.py file to invoke `manage.py makemigrations`, I need to check if the lib is integrating into the project properly (in my case apps are full-fledged plugins, I am using [GDAPS](https://gdaps.readthedocs.org)).

What is the best approach here?

- should I create a separate "test project" in a separate repo that uses my library and tests it?
- should I create a project within my library's tests directory and use that? CAVE python paths...
- should I not use the project at all and mimick everything - how?

Please give me at least a hint in some direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was googling the same question, and found that the "[Using the Django test runner to test reusable applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/advanced/#using-the-django-test-runner-to-test-reusable-applications)" section of the Advanced testing topics of the Django documentation gives a suitable common practice. It's a mixture of all three your approaches.

Basically you should create a *tests* package next to the application code, with a test_settings.py containing all the settings your library needs, and at least set the SECRET_KEY and INSTALLED_APPS variables.

```
SECRET_KEY = 'fake-key'
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "tests", "your-library"
]
```

Where "your-library" is the name of the libray you need to test.

In my case, I had to also add 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', as they where needed by my library.

Then you put all your tests into that package, eventual addictional models in a models.py file, and run them with a runtests.py that lives on the root of your repo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.test.utils import get_runner

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tests.test_settings'
    django.setup()
    TestRunner = get_runner(settings)
    test_runner = TestRunner()
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(["tests"])
    sys.exit(bool(failures))
```

It will use the test_settings.py as its settings file (os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tests.test_settings'), and run all the tests contained in the tests package.